# Let $f: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^3$ defined by $f(x,y) = (x^2 - 5y^2,ye^{2x},2x - \log(1+y^2))$ Suppose that $g:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ is of class $C^1$

Tags: matrices, function-and-relation-composition

Let $f: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^3$ defined by $f(x,y) = (x^2 - 5y^2,ye^{2x},2x - \log(1+y^2))$

Suppose that $g:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ is of class $C^1$ and $g(1,2) =(0,0)$ and $$
Dg(1,2)=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
$$ then $D(f \circ g)(1,2) = $

1. $$\begin{pmatrix}
   -15 & -20 \\
   4 & 6 \\
   2 & 4
   \end{pmatrix}
   $$
2. $$\begin{pmatrix}
   -15 & -20 \\
   3 & 4 \\
   2 & 4
   \end{pmatrix}
   $$
3. $$\begin{pmatrix}
   -15 & 4 & 2 \\
   -20 & 6 & 4
   \end{pmatrix}
   $$
4. $$\begin{pmatrix}
   -15 & 4 & 2 \\
   -20 & -6 & 4
   \end{pmatrix}
   $$

My Attempt:

Here range of $g$ contained in domain of $f$, so $f\circ g$ is well defined. Also $g(1,2) =(0,0)$ and $f(1,0) =(1,0,2)$ and $f(0,1) =(-5,1,-\log 2)$ where $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are standard basis of $\Bbb R^2$

I don't know how to solve this question. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, you know the chain rule. Otherwise it could be really difficult. It holds
$$
\begin{align*}
D(f\circ g)(1,2) &= Df(g(1,2))\cdot Dg(1,2)
\end{align*}
$$
You need to calculate $Df=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x} &\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}\\\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}\\\frac{\partial f_3}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial f_3}{\partial y}\end{pmatrix}$ and evaluate it at the point $(0,0)$. Then you have to multiply it with $Dg(1,2)=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{pmatrix}$.

Observe, that $f\circ g$ maps from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^3$. So you get the number of rows and columns of $D(f\circ g)$ .